# Why this array is not being set properly outside of foreach loop?

Tags: php, sql

I am fetching from my db using two queries and when i try to print the result inside the for each it does print all of it  but when I try to print it outside it doesn't print everything:

```
$arr_devices = [];
$sql1 = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE users.name = '$company_name'"; //finding the ids of the users of this company
if ($res = $db->query($sql1)) {
    $arr_id = $res->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    foreach ($arr_id as $company_id) {
        $sql = "SELECT
        devices.id, 
        devices.serial_imei, 
        devices.serial_no, 
        devices.type_id, 
        devices.cus_id, 
        devices.sales_date,
        device_types.name,
        device_types.manufacturer,
        device_types.device_no,
        device_types.barcode,
        users.id,
        users.name as manufacturer_name
        FROM devices
        INNER JOIN device_types 
        ON device_types.id = devices.type_id
        INNER JOIN users ON device_types.manufacturer = users.id
        WHERE devices.cus_id = " . $company_id['id'] . " ";
        $result = $db->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $arr_devices = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
        print_r($arr_devices);  //HERE IT PRINTS EVERYTHING I AM FETCHING
    }
    print_r($arr_devices);  //HERE IT DOESNT
}
```

See the comments in the code.

Comment: What do you mean with "everything"? Please provide an example print you get and accordingly what you expected.

Comment: @Dharman I am aware of that, I need to work on the security of my data later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the array every loop.

Use `$arr_devices[] = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

to append the result of your query to your array.

As a side note, using query inside loops is usually bad, cause it will demand too much of your database. Use just one query:

```
SELECT devices.id, 
    devices.serial_imei, 
    devices.serial_no, 
    devices.type_id, 
    devices.cus_id, 
    devices.sales_date,
    device_types.name,
    device_types.manufacturer,
    device_types.device_no,
    device_types.barcode,
    users.id,
    users.name as manufacturer_name
 FROM devices
INNER JOIN device_types 
   ON device_types.id = devices.type_id
INNER JOIN users ON device_types.manufacturer = users.id
WHERE devices.cus_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE users.name = '$company_name')
```

Then you can fetch all in one query, much faster.

Comment: this doesn't print anything.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you replaced `$arr_devices = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);` with my code? Just add `[]` after your variable.

Comment: I did as you suggested without the for loop, it works perfectly fine now! Thanks mate! I will accept your answer when SO allows me.

Comment: No problem, it's way better. If `$company_name` came from POST or GET data, then you should look for prepared statements, as using it directly will make your system vulnerable to SQL Injection attack.

Comment: I really need to work on the security, but for now, I just had to make it work.